# Laravel, Get row with highest version column from database

Tags: laravel

At the moment i have a 1 to many relationship between 2 models. A Machine model and a Document Model. 
A document can have multiple versions and i always related to my machine. Now i only want to show the documents with the latest or highest version.

I've tried to get the version from the document but then i can only return 1 document to my view instead of returning multiple documents. I've also tried to get the documents the following way but i get stuck with the steps i need to take after creating the loop:

```
$machine = Machine::find($id);
    $documents = $machine->documents;

    foreach($documents as $document)
    {

    }



    dd($documents);

    return view('machine.detail', compact('machine'));
```

So to specify my question: How can i return only the unique documents with the latest version to my view. So if file 1 has versions 1,2,3,10 and file 2 has versions 1,2,3 i want to return version 10 of file 1 and version 3 of file 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a unique key for each document that is shared for all the versions something like this should work.

```php
$documents = $machine->documents->groupBy('name of your unique key')->map(function($documents) {
    $latestVersion = $documents->max('version');
    return $documents->firstWhere('version', $latestVersion);
});
```

Explanation: The get the latest version from each document we first need to group all documents by a key to separate all the unqiue documents into multiple collections that contain the versions.

Then we need to map them into a new collection where we only get the document with the latest version.

Note: Dont forget to change `$machine = Machine::find($id);` to `$machine = Machine::with('documents')->find($id);` so you load the documents before hand. This will prevent the [n+1 query problem](https://kordes.dev/posts/laravel-and-n-1-problem)

Comment: The downside of this way is that it stores all the documents in the memory and then the code filters them. So if it is a page that needs to be optimized you need to look at doing the calculation in the database.

Comment: @Joeri good point. I think in that case something like `$machine->documents()->groupBy('name')->havingRaw('version = MAX(version)')->get()` could work

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly you can do the following.

```php
// Add this relation also on your model where your hasMany is on properly Machine.php
public function latestDocument()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Document::class)
        ->latest('version_column');
}
```

```php
// Controller
$machine = Machine::with(['latestDocument'])->findOrFail($id);

$document = $machine->latestDocument;

return view('machine.detail', compact('machine'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your awnser, i've tried the above and it returns 1 document with the latest version. Im trying to get all documents with the latest versions.